# DocuSign populate number fields in template

Tags: docusignapi

I'm testing out a DocuSign template I made using their [payload helper](http://iodocs.docusign.com/). I'm able to populate the custom text fields with the following body structure. However, any numeric field is not getting set. I tried including them as `textTabs` but they're not getting set. Does anyone know the correct format for these fields? There doesn't appear to be a `numericTabs` option.

```
    "templateRoles": [
            {
              "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                  {"tabLabel": "Address", "value": "5 Main St"},
                  // Phone not getting set
                  {"textLabel": "Phone", "value": "1234567891"},
                ]
              },
              "roleName": "Customer",
              "name": "Customer Name",
              "email": "myemail@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the label name, for the phone you are setting:

```
{"textLabel": "Phone", "value": "1234567891"},
```

you need `tabLabel` instead of `textLabel` like you have for the address

```
{"tabLabel": "Phone", "value": "1234567891"},
```

As long as you fix that and are using the same name you named the field in the template it will work.

Comment: thanks, that was just sloppy question asking on my end. I've been able to pinpoint the issue. I can post the value properly when I mask the value as `Text` by sending it as `{"tabLabel": "Tester","value":   "748329"}`. However when I change the mask in the UI to `Numeric` the same request doesn't get posted. I've also tried changing the value to an `int` instead of a `string`. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe the quotes are turning it into a `string`?  What if you try `748329` without the quotes?

Comment: tried that with no luck. any ideas? if not no sweat, can just make everything a text field

Comment: What does the template definition look like for this field?  Can you copy that portion of the xml and post here?